# German words for different cleaning agents (shampoo, body wash, detergent, etc.)

Tags: english-to-german

I've been trying to look up words for shampoo, conditioner, detergent, etc.  However, I've only a few months of German under my belt and cannot distinguish the nuances between words that the dictionaries are giving me.

For example, for *shampoo* I've seen *Shampoo*, *Schampon*, and *Haarwaschmittel*.  For *conditioner*, I've seen *Pflegespülung*, *Konditionierer*, *Haarspülung*, and *Weichspüler*.

All the words I'd like to translate are as follows:

- shampoo (for hair)
- conditioner (for hair)
- laundry detergent
- body wash
- shaving cream

Also, would I be understood if I asked for "Seife/Waschmittel für die Haare" if I needed to improvise the word for, say, shampoo?

P.S. I've been using [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com/english-german), [Word Reference](http://www.wordreference.com/), and [Leo](https://www.leo.org/ende/index_de.html).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Welcome in the multilingual world of cosmetics! As it stands, there *are* German words for all these things, but sometimes the English (or "Denglish") word is used more often. So let me give you an overview:

Washing hair:
*Shampoo* (sometimes *Shampoon* or *Schampon*) has become the standard term, replacing the more oldfashioned *Haarwaschmittel*.

Softening hair:
Here a plethora of terms ares used: *(Haar-)Spülung* *Pflegespülung*, *Conditioner* or, more intense *(Haar)-Kur*. Marketing speak has come up with a few more fluffy terms like *SOS-Repair*. For everything that is beyond the apply-and-rinse kind, all bets are off and it's most likely some English phrase or English-German mixup like *Leave-in Kur*.

Cleaning your body:
There is the good old *Seife* (soap), that has seen a bit of a revival lately. But if the bar-shaped thingy is not genuine soap it may be called *Waschstück* or *Syndet*, both being rather medicinal terms. In liquid form it's either *Flüssigseife* or sometimes *Cremeseife* (in the dispenser on the sink) or *Duschgel* (for the body). And if the professional language maulers (aka advertisers) had a go at it, it may say *Body Wash* or something completely different on the bottle, leaving you to guess/infer the intended use. I just found two bottles in my bathroom that say "Dusche" and "Erfrischungsdusche" but contain shower gel, not a shower stall. Sigh.

Shaving:
Here it's mostly the texture that decides between *Rasierseife*, *Rasierschaum* and *Rasiergel*.

Laundry:
Surprisingly, this is where a simple *Waschmittel* will suffice, sometimes specifying texture again, like *Waschpulver*, *Flüssigwaschmittel* or *Waschmitteltabs* (the oversized "tablets") or detailing the use as *Vollwaschmittel* (for whites) / *Feinwaschmittel* (delicates) / *Colorwaschmittel* (Denglish rearing its ugly head again). If you like you can also add *Weichspüler* to soften your laundry (Caveat: this is not for your hair unlike you assumed in your question!) or *Fleckensalz* or *Bleiche* / *Bleichmittel* to remove tough stains.

Of course you may always make up phrases like "X to wash Y" - there may be the occasional smug salesperson, but mostly you will get the desired results and extra points for creativity!

Comment: This answer is very helpful! I admit that as a native German speaker, I can never remember and am constantly confused by whether products named "Shampoo" refer to something for the hair or for the body. I always have to check the small text on the packaging to find implicit hints, such as "anti-scall" (-> it's for hair). I *so* wish they could return to the term "Haarwaschmittel".

Comment: I've never seen *Shampoon* yet, but otherwise I can wholeheartedly agree! +1 Note that *Shampoo* can also be written *Schampoo*.

Comment: Wow!  Thanks for the thorough response.  This is exactly what I needed.  I may even print this and keep it in my pocket when I go shopping.

Comment: +1 for creativity and for mentioning extra points for creativity

Comment: I'd not count *Colorwaschmittel* as Denglish. Isn't that good old Latin?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I've heard (but not read) Körper-Shampoo used for Duschgel (Shower gel).

Comment: @Sumyrda: Come to think of it, I think I have also heard "Haarshampoo". Tautological in theory, but actually clarifying.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz The question is not, where the word *originates* from, but from which language it *came into German*. Otherwise there could be no French loanwoards, only Latin ones. And in this case, the product likely came from the states (as they couldn’t write *colour* ‘correctly’ ;) )

Comment: @Jan, wahrscheinlich hatte das Englische einen Einfluss, aber die Aussprache ist nicht englisch, sondern wie in [*kolorieren*](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemid=GC00368).

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Yes but if it derived from that, it should be with a *k*. Also, laundry detergent for coloured laundry has been around for such a long time, that it could well have entered the language before English pronounciation was widely known.

Comment: @Jan, I do not claim that the word is derived directly from *kolorieren* (or *colorieren* or *coloriren*), but it coexists nicely with this word that has been in the German language for a very long time, so it fits in.

Answer (score 3):

- Shampoo - Shampoo or Schampu is definitely the most common. *Haarwaschmittel* sounds a bit more general, but can be used as a synonym for Shampoo. It probably just is the native German word. I have never heard *Schampon*.
- Conditioner - *(Haar)spülung* or *(Pflege)spülung* feel equally common. *Konditionierer* sounds like a bastard anglicism.
- Laundry detergent - *Waschpulver* or *Waschmittel*
- Body wash - *Duschgel*
- Shaving cream - *Rasierschaum* or *Rasiergel*
- *Weichspüler* - softener
- *Seife* - soap

> Also, would I be understood if I asked for "Seife/Waschmittel für der Haare" if I needed to improvise the word for, say, shampoo?

You would be understood, but "Seife" sounds very weird here.

Answer (score 1):

#### • shampoo (for hair) — das Haarshampoo; das Shampoo; das Haarwaschmittel

#### • conditioner (for hair) — der Haar-Conditioner; die Haarspülung; die Pflegespülung;

#### • body wash — das Duschgel;

- die Duschcreme (when added with extra skin moisturiser)

#### • shaving cream — die Rasiercreme; der Rasierschaum

*by type:*

- der Rasierschaum (foam, usually in spray cans)
- das Rasiergel (gel, in spray cans or tubes)
- die Rasiercreme (in tubes or tubs)
- die Rasierseife (old-style shaving soap)

#### • hand detergent/soap — die Handseife / Seife

#### • hand sanitizer/antiseptic (gel) — das Handdesinfektionsmittel

#### • laundry detergent — *generic term:* das Waschmittel;

*types:*

- das Vollwaschmittel (for 'white' laundry, usually contains
  small amount of a bleaching agent)
- das Buntwaschmittel, Farbwaschmittel (for coloured textiles, without bleaching agent, but usually containing optical brightener to make colours more lively)
- das Feinwaschmittel (for fine fabrics, without bleach and optical brightener) There is also an extra type marketed for black-coloured fabrics.
- das Wollwaschmittel (a type of Feinwaschmittel for wool)
- das Daunenwaschmittel (for textiles with down/feather filling)

*forms:*

- powder: das Waschpulver (Vollwaschpulver, Feinwaschpulver)
- liquid: das Flüssigwaschmittel
- tablets: die Waschmitteltabs (plural)

#### • laundry sanitizer (non-bleaching disinfectant) — Wäschedesinfektionsmittel

#### • fabric conditioner/softener — der Weichspüler

#### • fabric bleach — die Wäschebleiche; das Bleichmittel